# Linq to Entities Expression Tree - Comparing String Values as Integers

Tags: linq-to-entities, compare, expression-trees, varchar

How can I build a SQL Server compatible expression tree that can compare a string as if it were an integer?

My table contains phone numbers (e.g. "01234000000") and I want my dynamically created query to return a range of phone numbers.

The SQL I want is something like this:

```
SELECT PhoneNumber 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE PhoneNumber BETWEEN '01234000000' AND '01234000099'
```

which even though PhoneNumber is a VARCHAR it's perfectly valid SQL and returns the results as you'd expect.

I've tried a couple of things (upper bound omitted for clarity):

```
Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, "01234000000") // doesn't work on strings

Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
    Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(Int64)), 
    Expression.Constant(1234000000, typeof(Int64))) // not supported by the SQL Query Provider
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? If not, then is it possible to extend the Query Provider to add this in myself and how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, SQL isn't really doing a numeric compare, it's doing a alpha compare. But since you're working with phone numbers which are all the same length, that difference should be immaterial.

You can do the following though from within EF:

```
var lowerBound = "01234000000";
var upperBound = "01234000099";
var results = MyTable
    .Where(t => t.PhoneNumber.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 && t.PhoneNumber.CompareTo(upperBound) <= 0);
```

According to LinqPad, that generates the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '01234000000'
DECLARE @p1 VarChar(1000) = '01234000099'

SELECT [t0].[PhoneNumber]
FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[PhoneNumber] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[PhoneNumber] <= @p1)
```